# laboratory database software

Tags: open-source, database, api, scientific-computing

I am working in a small (three person) physics laboratory and would like a robust and convenient way to log data. Writing a custom python script to iterate through the lines of a data file, converting the strings to numbers, and organizing into columns seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

I'm imagining the database software provides some dll where users can conveniently interface with the data. Access through a socket or tcp/ip connection would be another obvious way to interface, as well as some simple graphical interface with some simple plotting features.

Data will be almost always fed in by another program that is acquiring the data, and likewise data will be typically accessed and processed by some program, so the manual entry / manipulation focus of typical spreadsheet programs would not be appropriate.

Does there exist any open source software tailored to this application? Some nominal level of programming/computer ability can be assumed of the users.

Comment: Hi and welcome on Software recommendations. The question is quite broad however. Please be more specific: What kind of data are you talking about, and which amount thereof? Do you actually need to write log files or just iterating through existing ones?

Comment: With such a broad description, any spreadsheet software seems valid: easy to maintain, with plotting abilities, few setup required. Just needs a client to add the entries.